# (Spoiler) Can the "The Crane Returns on the Wind" interlude quest be played "out-of-order"?

Tags: genshin-impact

Base on [Mihoyo official post](https://genshin.mihoyo.com/en/news/detail/18237), the new interlude quest "The Crane Returns on the Wind" unlock criteria is

> Complete the Archon Quest "Chapter I: Act III - A New Star Approaches"

This means that the quest can be played before visiting Inazuma and playing thru the Archeon quest there.

The new quest involves

> the rebuild of the Jade Camber that has previously been sacrificed to defeat the Lord of the Vortrex during the Liyue Archeon quest arc.

For this reason, it would logically seem that the quest is incompatible with

> The world quests "Fishing for Jade" and "Return of the Jade Chamber" which have the npc Baiwen talk about the ***future*** plans to rebuild the Jade Chamber

Given the above, can this end up causing a sequence break in the story? More specifically, what would happen if

> a player does not complete Return of the Jade Chamber before playing "The Crane Returns on the Wind"  and thus getting the Jade Chamber back? Is "Return of the Jade Chamber" still available, resulting in the NPC talking about rebuilding the Chamber in  while it is already there or does it get removed and thus is forever-missable if not played in-time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The possible inconsistencies introduced by "The Crane Returns on the Wind" were indeed noticed by the developers and so completing the quest earlier produces some changes in the game.

Specifically,

> the quest "Fishing for Jade" gets altered to mention that "while the Jade Chamber has been rebuilt, pieces of the old one are still floating in the water. "Return of the Jade Chamber?" has the dialogue changed so that the items you are sent to retrieve will be used for internal decoration instead that for the reconstruction.
>  The altered versions of the two quests can be seen on Youtube here:
>  [Genshin Impact - Fishing For Jade, But After Rebuilding the Jade Chamber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_iQzlTjij5g)
>  [Genshin Impact - Return of the Jade Chamber?, But After Rebuilding the Jade Chamber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjraTgSgn_Y)